# Auth::Attempt(username,password) doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I am really new to laravel but had experience using PHP, I have this problem with the Auth::attempt() method. It seems that even thought $request->get() gets the value the attempt method doesn't work. I tried checking my Database Table using Schema::hasTable and yes it exists. I am not using the email and password instead I am using a username and password for the login.

LoginController.php

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(){
        return view('pages.login');
    }

    public function dashboard(){
        return view('pages.dashboard');
    }

public function checklogin(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
        'Username'    => 'required|string|min:5',
        'Password' => 'required|min:6'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/login')
            ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
            ->withInput($request->except('Password')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
    }else{
        $userdata = array(
            'Password'  => $request->get('Password'),
            'Username'     => $request->get('Username')
        );
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata,true)) {

            // validation successful!
            echo 'SUCCESS!';
            echo  Auth::user()->FirstName;
        } else {

            // validation not successful, send back to form
            echo "ERROR!";
        }

    }
    //Just checking if the value was really been posted
    echo $request->get('username').$request->get('password');
}

public function logout()
{
 Auth::logout();
 return redirect('/');
}
}
```

Here is the model I created

UsersInfo.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthAuthenticatable;

class UsersInfo extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use AuthAuthenticatable;

    protected $table = 'UsersInfo';

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'Username','Password','MobileNum','AccountNum','FirstName','LastName','Address'
    ];
    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->Password;
      }
}
```

auth.php

```
    <?php

return [

    

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'UsersInfo',
    ],

    

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'UsersInfo',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'UsersInfo',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    

    'providers' => [
        'Users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'UsersInfo' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\UsersInfo::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    

    'passwords' => [
        'UsersInfo' => [
            'provider' => 'UsersInfo',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Comment: it looks fine, plz make sure of your entered username that it doesn't have any whitespaces after it and also make sure you entered correct username and password

Comment: I entered t he correct credentials, Iam using SQLSRV, I kinda changed something on my auth.php in the config folder.  Instead of the modal User and provider Users, I changed it to UsersInfo.

Comment: and UserInfo is not having your credintials?

Comment: I think so, but I was able to insert data using database seeder. Do I need to specify my increment Id?

Comment: no, So user table doesn't have any credintials now and all your credintials are in user_info table ?

Comment: I don't have a User table, didn't migrate it since I already have a users_info table where my username and password is stored.

Comment: that means it should work, can you copy your auth.php in the question?

Comment: yes it should work, I just edited it

Comment: try to keep the auth.php as normal before your edits and just modify the providers:
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' =>App\UsersInfo::class,
],

Comment: $userdata = array(
            'Password'  => $request->get('Password'),
            'Username'     => $request->get('Username')
        );

must be lowerkeys ....

Comment: I tried the one you said, I still get an error, I tried 'providers' => [
        'UsersInfo' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\UsersInfo::class,
        ],
but it didn't work

Comment: By default laravel consider email and password as login credentials, so you need to customize the login process

Comment: @PalakJadav I noticed, and I did that, right now it did work, the wrong thing I did was the field I was passing the value, instead of "Password" it should've been "password".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing the credentials to `attempt` the field holding the password **must** be named `password` (in this exact case). This is how the user provider knows what field in the credentials is supposed to be the password. The password is something that is checked after a record is found and is not part of the query.

```
$userdata = [
    'password' => $request->input('Password'),
    'Username' => $request->input('Username'),
];
```

Passwords are hashed, you can not directly compare this to the database value, the `password` field is not part of the query to find the user. Every thing else in the credentials array is a where condition.

Comment: I named the field 'Password' , I tried to print the values using _"echo $request->get(string) "_ and got the values.

Comment: it doesn't matter what you named the field in the database ... when passing the credentials to `attempt` the field in those credentials that holds the password **MUST** be named `password` .. this has nothing to do with the name of the field in the database

Comment: it should all be lowercase? , Okay I get it now. I got the success message, but the problem is the _"if(isset(Auth::user->userid))"_ isn't getting any value. Thank you!

Comment: the field that is holding the password in the credentials must be `password` (lowercase), every other key in the credentials is what ever case those particular fields in the database actually are ... it is only this `password` field that is special in that regard

Comment: what would this `userid` attribute be? this model has a primary key of `id`

Comment: I got it now. Thank you so much for explaining!

Comment: one more question, how can I pass the value to my dashboard after logging in? can I get the value using _"Auth::user()->Username"_?